# leaflet layer group default value

Tags: leaflet, layer

I have 4 layers overlay group on a base map, i need to make weather group layer is select default on the map.

```
this.weather = L.layerGroup()
    this.wind = L.featureGroup()
    this.humd = L.layerGroup();
    this.rain = L.layerGroup();


    // Base-Maps with Overlayes
    var mixed = {
      "Grayscale": grayscale, // BaseMaps
      "Streets": streets,       // BaseMaps
      "Metro": metro,               // BaseMaps
      "weather": this.weather,  // OverlayMaps
      "wind": this.wind,                // OverlayMaps
      "humd": this.humd,                // OverlayMaps
      "rain": this.rain,                // OverlayMaps
    };


    this.map = new Map('mapId').setView([33, 44], 6);
    tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y} 
    {r}.png', {
      attribution: '2019 © منظومة ارصاد العراق',
      minZoom: 5,
      maxZoom: 6
    }).addTo(this.map);

    L.control.layers(mixed).addTo(this.map);
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed

```
    this.map = new Map('mapId').setView([33, 44], 6);
    tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
      attribution: '2019 © منظومة ارصاد العراق',
      minZoom: 5,
      maxZoom: 6
    }).addTo(this.map);

   // just  add any layer you would like , 

    this.map.addLayer(this.weather)

/// then rest of layers here 
    L.control.layers(mixed,null,{collapsed:false} ).addTo(this.map);
```